# How to form Hessian matrix in BFGS Quasi-Newton Method

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, optimization, supervised-learning

I came across [this](http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/toolbox/nnet/backpr11.html) link. In BFGS Quasi-Newton Method, a Hessian matrix is used in weight updation. Is there any resource where I can find how this hessian matrix was obtained along with a clear description of the process, as to why Hessian matrix has been taken? I could not understand the wiki article.

Comment: Did you read the Wikipedia articles on [BFGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden–Fletcher–Goldfarb–Shanno_algorithm) and the [Hessian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In optimization, you are looking for minima and maxima of a certain function **f**. Equivalently, under certain derivative conditions, you are looking for the zeros of **g**, the derivative of **f**.

The first equation of your link describes one step of the Newton Method - not BFGS. It involves the Hessian of **f** which is not accessible in practice - it's ineficcient in terms of time and memory storage. Due to this fact, some have developed methods not to calculate the hessian directly.

Thanks to Taylor expansion, you can write

> **g**(x) = **g**(y) + **g'**(y)(x-y) + **Θ**(|x-y|²)

Replacing x by x(k+1) and y by x(k), and **g'** by the Hessian of **f** gives you (with the following convention : **g**(k+1) = **g**( x(k+1) )

> **g**(k+1) ≈ **g**(k) + **∇²f**(x(k+1)) ( x(k+1) - x(k) )
>
> **H**(k+1) (x(k+1) - x(k)) ≈ **g**(k+1) - **g**(k)
> where **H**(k) aims to approximate ∇²**f**(x(k)). But instead of calculating it at each step, we'll try to *approximate* it thanks to the previous **H**(k-1)

In 1970, Broyden, Fletcher, Goldfard and Shamo proposed a rank 2 update of **H**(k), ie

> **H**(k+1) = **H**(k) + Term1 + Term2

where Term1 does not depend on **H** and Term2 depends on **H(k)**. You can find these terms [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%E2%80%93Fletcher%E2%80%93Goldfarb%E2%80%93Shanno_algorithm).

But this solves only the time issue, not the memory storage. As for that, some have developed [Limited-memory BFGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited-memory_BFGS) (or L-BFGS) to limit the amount of memory used.